# useQuery returns undefined after redirect with useMutations [Apollo/React hooks]

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

In my app I have 2 public routes (Login and register page), and a PrivateRoute, which verifies with JWT if the 'auth-token' in localStorage is valid.

In my Register page I use the 'useMutations' hook to register the user. I set a token in LocalStorage and with react router I get send to the main component ('/') which is the chat.

I have made a 'me' query, which needs my 'auth-token' in order to fetch the specific user from the DB.

Problem is, that after the user gets redirected to the chat after successfully registering, the useMutations goes too fast and returns undefined. If I would refresh the page it fetches the 'me' query perfectly.

I've already tried using setTimeout on the redirect because it could be of the token not set fast enough. But that's not it.

I've tried with the useLazyQuery hook, but that didn't work either. It also needed a refresh, because the first time it also gave undefined.

```
/// my register component ///

const Register = props => {
  const [createUser] = useMutation(CREATE_USER, {
    onCompleted({ createUser }) {
      localStorage.setItem('auth-token', createUser.token);
      props.history.push('/');
    }
  });

  return (
    <InputWrapper>
      <h2>Signup for DevChat</h2>
      {/* {error !== null && <Alert>{error}</Alert>} */}

      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          userName: '',
          email: '',
          password: '',
          confirmPassword: ''
        }}
        validationSchema={RegisterSchema}
        onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
          createUser({ variables: values });
          resetForm({
            userName: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            confirmPassword: ''
          });
        }}
      >
```

```
const UserPanel = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_LOGGED_IN_USER, {
    context: localStorage.getItem('auth-token')
  });

  const [toggleOn, setToggleOn] = useState(false);

  const handleSignOut = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('auth-token');
    ///refresh page should redirect to /login
    window.location.reload();
  };

  const toggleDropDown = () => {
    setToggleOn(!toggleOn);
  };

  return (
    <ProfileWrapper>
      {loading ? <span>Loading ...</span> : console.log(data)}

      <ProfileGroup onClick={toggleDropDown}>
        <ProfileIcon className='fas fa-user' />
        <ProfileTitle>
          {/* {loading && called ? <span>Loading ...</span> : console.log(data)} */}
          {error ? console.log(error) : null}
        </ProfileTitle>
        <DropDownIcon
          className={toggleOn ? 'fas fa-chevron-up' : 'fas fa-chevron-down'}
        />
```

```
/// my console.log(the first time)
undefined
UserPanel.js:95 Error: GraphQL error: jwt malformed

UserPanel.js:91 {}
```

```
/// my console.log() after a refresh:

{me: {…}}
me:
age: null
email: "test@gmail.com"
id: "599c5f9a-f97e-4964-a707-138c2159cff8"
userName: "Test"
__typename: "User"
__proto__: Object
```

Would like to know what i'm doing wrong ... Thanks in advance for the help and for reading this... :)

Bert

EDIT 1: Set TimeOut didn't work on 'props.history.push('/')'

EDIT 2: Solution found. As this was my first project with GraphQL and Apollo, I didn't know that Apollo Boost was like the `create-react-app` from Apollo, I need to config everything with `Apollo-Client` (the more customisable package). I followed the [official docs here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/boost-migration/) for the migration from `Apollo Boost` to Client.

Answer (score 0):

I think `localStorage.setItem` is an asynchronous function. The issue was you already pushed the route though it is not done writing the token to localStorage.

My hack solution for this is adding a delay before you push the route

```
    onCompleted({ createUser }) {
      localStorage.setItem('auth-token', createUser.token);
      setTimeout(() => {
        props.history.push('/');
      }, 500)
    }
```

Edit: seems like the issue is the apollo client initialization

```
  const httpAuthLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Hi, I had already tried using setTimeout on the redirect because it could be of the token not set fast enough. But that's not it. ... Damn ... Even if i put it on 5000 ms it needs a refresh to run ...

Comment: do you mean it's still not getting the auth-token from the localStorage?

Comment: Could it have something to do with my apolloClient setup (which is with apollo-boost) ?
I edited original post...

Comment: I suspect your server is expecting Bearer Authorization and you did not supply the token. like this https://github.com/jasper95/interlink-graphql/blob/master/src/apollo/initApollo.js#L63

Comment: Will migrate from Apollo boost to Apollo Client, to see if this will be better. Thanks for the help and link :) Will get back to you :)

Comment: Worked. Thanks man :) I would give upvote, but not possible since i don't have 15 reputation points.... ;(

Answer (score 0):

Could it have something to do with my client setup?
It's with apollo-boost package instead of apollo-client ...

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import ApolloClient, { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-boost';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Register from './components/auth/Register';
import Chat from './components/pages/Chat';
import PrivateRoute from './components/auth/PrivateRoute';

// const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('auth-token')}`
  }
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Chat} />
          <Route path='/register' component={Register} />
          <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};

const RootWithAuth = withRouter(App);
```